# Deleting Files When Browser Closes Without Dialog ASP.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, browser, exit

I am trying to delete a file when a broswer closes without a Dialog box opening to ask to continue.

Right now I have code that looks like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript" >
    window.onbeforeunload = deletePDF;
    function deletePDF() {

        __doPostBack('', '');
        return true;
    }

</script>

Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If Page.IsPostBack Then
       System.IO.File.Delete(tempPath & pdfFileName)
    End If
```

If I have the function return nothing, the page hangs until I close it myself.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It is impossible to do this reliably.

Comment: What makes it impossible?

Comment: Browsers won't wait for your request before unloading the page.

Comment: Can't be done for a number of reasons. Primarily, your browser does not have access to the underlying file system.

Comment: Is it still jsut as unreliable with the dialog box?

I've been able to delete the files with this when testing it.

Comment: are you trying to delete files of the server hard drive or the local user's PC? this code looks like it's firing off to the server, and removing the file from the server disk, the browser is then waiting for the server process to complete.